# How to do an INNER JOIN without getting duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. A `jobs` table (with job.user_id) and a `users` table with `user.id`

I am trying to select all jobs and include username from users table, but I'm getting double the number of results I should be:

```
  async getAll(context: any) {
    const all = await db.queryEntries(`
        SELECT j.*, u.username FROM jobs as j, users as u
       INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.user_id = u.id ORDER BY j.created_at DESC
    `);

    context.response.body = all;
  }
```

I get two of everything. How do I just add 'username' where job.user_id = user.id?

**users:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id string primary key,
   email string unique,
   hashed_password string, 
   created_at TEXT, 
   updated_at TEXT, 
   username TEXT, 
   contactme INTEGER DEFAULT 1, 
   phone TEXT
);
```

**jobs:**

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
   id STRING PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id STRING NOT NULL,
   title STRING NOT NULL,
   description STRING NOT NULL,
   pay STRING NOT NULL,
   type STRING NOT NULL,
   created_at TEXT,
   updated_at TEXT, 
   contact TEXT
);
```

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). That includes sample data and expected output.

Comment: i added schemas

Comment: @chovy Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: That's a start. Now you need to add the sample data and expected output.

Comment: `FROM jobs as j, users as u INNER JOIN jobs ON....`  Is that a typo? Because if it actually executes (not sure if it would in sqllite) it would end up joining to jobs twice.

Comment: yeah i think that's what it was doing. if I from 'users as u" from the "FROM" it works.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since it was essentially a typo, voting to close.

Comment: wasn't really a typo. I thought that's how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the "FROM users":

```
        SELECT j.*, u.username FROM jobs as j
        INNER JOIN users u ON j.user_id = u.id ORDER BY j.created_at DESC
```

This produces only one result now.